# JSTL and c:when test condition

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

how can I check and use userLoggedIn to testify the condition.
I am new and I have search alot. there must be a silly mistake.

index.jsp

```
<div id="sign-in">
    <c:choose> 
        <c:when test="${userLoggedIn == 1}"> 
             Welcome <c:out value="${loginID}" /> | Logout
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>Log-in</c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</div>
```

some verification servlet

```
int userLoggedIn = 0;

if(loginID.equals("guest@guest.com") && password.equals("guest")){
    userLoggedIn = 1;
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    //     out.println("login successful");

} else {
    //   getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    out.println("login failed");
}
```

Comment: why is userLoggedIn not boolean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to store the information in the desired scope, which is usually the session scope for case of logged-in users.

Add the following line *after* `userLoggedIn = 1;`.

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("userLoggedIn", userLoggedIn);
```

That's basically all you need to change.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this `int` (and `boolean` as commented by BevynQ) approach is rather "primitive". You'd usually store the entire `User` entity obtained from the DB in the session instead. E.g.

```
User user = userService.find(username, password);

if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
    response.sendRedirect("home");
} else {
    request.setAttribute("message", "Unknown login, please try again");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

with

```html
<c:when test="${not empty user}">
```

which allows easy access of all its properties like

```html
<p>Welcome, <c:out value="${user.name}" /></p>
```

Comment: Also need to access in JSTL as: - `${sessionScope.userLoggedIn}`

Comment: @Rohit: That's unnecessary. Please read a sane JSP/Servlet tutorial. This approach is only necessary if you happen to have the same attribute in page or request scope as well, which would after all be plain bad design. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: @BalusC.. Oh Yes. I forgot that the attribute will automatically be searched in order.